# Google App Engine Multiple parents for an Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm setting up a college student database in the App Engine. I need to be able to list students registered for a class. I have Student and Class as Entities. The problem is a student can be registered for multiple classes therefore I need to be able to have multiple Class entities as parents for a Student. Is this possible? Documentation does not discuss multiple parents.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194505/google-app-engine-multiple-child-parent) says Python supports it, but I can' find anything for Java.

If not do I have to manually store Student IDs as a member data in Class?

Comment: in this question the situation is opposite, two children and one parent for both. 
btw, why you want to have multiple parents? to use with transactions or just because it's a natural relation?

Comment: I was thinking Class as parent and Student as child. When a student registers for multiple classes a Student will have multiple Class parents. To use with transactions, so given a Class key I can list all its children.

Comment: I have built a systems that has over 5000 active students in app engine.  We used an enrolment entity that is owned (ancestor) by the student and holds a reference to the Course/Class enrolled in, along with things like date of enrolment, etc..., term etc..  This way students can have multiple enrolments, an update to the enrolment is minor.  You store redundant data in the enrolment entity like course name student name etc.,. to make queries more per-formant.

Answer (score 0):

For transactions I suggest to introduce a new synthetic parent, that will be parent for group of both Class and Student entities. If that's possible in your situation. Or create a third entity that will hold relations of multiple ids, like:

```
class StudentClasses {
   Long studentId
   Long[] classesIds 
}
```

So you'll be able to update *student->classes* relation in one update.

Also avoid to create a root superparent, or you'll lose in performance (and will get a lot of locks most likely). And read carefully about parent-children conception in GAE, it's likely you don't really need it in your situation.

Comment: I think I was thinking this wrong. I don't think I have a use case such that I need a student->classes or class->students update operation. I can simply store the studentIDs in the Class entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you don't need to make Class entity as parent to student entity, because a student can exist without a class. So I believe, you just want to create a relationship between class and student. if so then you can create a relationship in which a student can have many classes.And also you can make a query to find all the students belonging to the any given class. You can visit to the documentation for more information about relationship [objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities)

In your Student Entity model add following line:

```
List<Ref<Class>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now while creating an student you need to create a relationship with the already created class or You can also assign a new class to the already created student(depends on your requirement)
  [this question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813998/objectify-filter-entities-with-parent-key/39096814#39096814)