# Objectify filter entities with parent key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have written a piece of code that fetches entities from google datastore by filtering the entity with the supplied parent key. When I run the code I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

I know the problem is with the way I am creating the parent key, can you please guide me how to effectively create a parent key for this use case?

I am getting the below exception in `Myservice.java` line 8

```
    Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception 
- Class hierarchy for class java.lang.Class has no @Entity annotation
```

**Appengine v1.9.36,
Objectify v5.1.7, 
JDK v1.7**

Below is a sample code

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Cache;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

    @Entity
    @Cache
    public class ParentEntity {

        @Id
        Long id;

        String name;

        String value;

        public static Key<ParentEntity> getKey(Long id){
            return Key.create(ParentEntity.class, id);
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

Another entity class

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Cache;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Parent;

@Entity
@Cache
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Parent Key<ParentEntity> application;

    String city;

    public static Key<ChildEntity> getKey(Long id){
        return Key.create(Key.create(ParentEntity.class), ChildEntity.class, id);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Key<ParentEntity> getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(Key<ParentEntity> application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

ServiceLaver that uses Objectify to fetch entities

```
import java.util.List;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class MyService{

    public List<ChildEntity> filterByID(Long id){
        return ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(ChildEntity.class)
            .filterKey(ChildEntity.getKey(id)).first().now();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your statement `return Key.create(Key.create(ParentEntity.class), ChildEntity.class, id);` the part `Key.create(ParentEntity.class)` should have an id as well, like `Key.create(ParentEntity.class, parentId)`. You cannot create a filter that uses a wildcard on the ancestor key. That only works the other way around with an ancestor query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change Your ParentEntity's method  :

```
public static Key<ParentEntity> getKey(Long id){
            return Key.create(ParentEntity.class, id);
        }
```

to:

```
 public String getWebSafeKey(){
                    return Key.create(ParentEntity.class, id).getString();
            }
```

Now when you insert a parent entity then in response it will give you **websafe key** of that parent entity. Use this websafe key whenever you wants to access this inserted parent entity.

After that change:

```
public List<ChildEntity> filterByID(Long id){
        return ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(ChildEntity.class)
            .filterKey(ChildEntity.getKey(id)).first().now();
    }
```

To:

```
public List<ChildEntity> filterByID(String parentWebSafeKey){
        return ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(ChildEntity.class)
            .ancestor(Key.create(parentWebSafeKey)).first().now();
    }
```

Don't forget to create relationship between ParentEntity and ChildEntity while creating child entity using:

```
child_entity.application = Ref.create(parent_entity_key);
```