# How to get an entity that has parent reference?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

In my Spring project and using Google App Engine, I'm trying to get an entity from datastore, but in this case this entity has a @Parent relation. I only have the id from the entity, a this point unaware information about Parent relation.
I tried different querys, using `ancestor` `filterKey`, at this moment I have this:

```
@Override
public House getNotRestrictions(Long id){
      return objectifyService.ofy().load().type(House.class).filterKey(Key.create(House.class, id)).first().now();
}
```

My model is something like this:

```
@Entity
public class House {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  //other attributes

  @Index
  @Parent
  public Key<User> createdBy;

  //methods getter and setters
}
```

When I execute the query, it returns to me and null entity. But the id into the datastore exists.

Comment: Following answer could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813998/objectify-filter-entities-with-parent-key/39096814#39096814

Answer (score 1):

Every entity has a key that includes its kind, ID/name, and kind + ID/name of all of its ancestors. If you create a key without passing ancestor information, this key will be *different* from the entity you are trying to retrieve.

Also note that you can have many entities with the same kind and ID, if they have different parents.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways:

```
//1. creating the full key with parent:
Key<House> houseKey = Key.create(Key.create(User.class, userId), House.class, id);

//2. or using the webSafeString key representation which contains the whole key path including namespace and parents:
String webSafeKey = "<encoded key as string>";
Key<House> houseKey = Key.<House>create(webSafe)

//Then you can fetch the entity:
House house = ofy().load().key(houseKey).now();
```

Since you mentioned you don't know the parent. You could start using the webSafeString instead - see [Key.toWebSafeString()](http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.8/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html#toWebSafeString--) method